# Maven: Compile external dependencies within pom.xml

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml, git-submodules

We have a `Common` git repository containing a parent `pom.xml` and some modules. The parent `pom.xml` looks like this (simplified):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <!-- Utility classes -->
    <module>utils</module>
    <!-- Data transfer objects -->
    <module>dto</module>
</modules>

</dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Version of the module -->
            <groupId>group</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The `dependencyManagement` is used to provide consistent versioning across all modules.

Now we want to use parts of the `Common` modules in other projects (own git repository each) and still keep the `dependencyManagement`. Thus, we created, for instance, a `ProjectX` repository and added `Common` as an `git-submodule`. `ProjectX` has the following `pom.xml` (simplified):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../Common/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

</dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This way, we can use classes of `Common.utils` and have dependency consistency. However, after each update of `Common` we have to call:

```
mvn clean install
```

in the `Common git-submodule` for `ProjectX pom.xml` to find the utils dependency.

**Question:**

- Can the `maven` command be integrated into the pom.xml?
- Is there a better way to handle the submodule dependency?

Answer (score 0):

The construction with the git submodule is unfortunate. I would not do it, this is not Maven philosophy.

I would separate two things:

- If you need one of the modules outside the multi-module project, just declare it as dependency in the usual way.
- If you want to share configuration or dependencyManagement between the multi-module project and other projects, construct a parent pom that you use for the different projects (may they be multi-module or not).